# Spring CriteriaBuilder ignore null values

Tags: java, spring, hibernate-criteria

I create a `CriteriaBuilder` for my GeoMaps. But these criterias are not required and can get the value null. I try to build with a if cases different searchstatements but i think its not the best way. 
Is there a better way to say my CriteriaBuilder if the value is null you should ignore this on the search?

**Filter Example:**

```
UserSpecification specName =
                    new UserSpecification(new SearchCriteria("name", ":", data.getName()));
UserSpecification specEnv =
                    new UserSpecification(new SearchCriteria("env", ":", data.getEnv()));

...

if(data.getEnv().isEmpty()){
    List list = gisMapRepository.findAll(Specification.where(specName));
}
```

**Userspecification.java:**

```
public class UserSpecification implements Specification<GeoMap> {

    private SearchCriteria criteria;
    public UserSpecification(SearchCriteria criteria) {
        this.criteria = criteria;
    }

    @Override
    public Predicate toPredicate
            (Root<GeoMap> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder builder) {

        if (criteria.getOperation().equalsIgnoreCase(":")) {
            if (root.get(criteria.getKey()).getJavaType() == String.class) {
                return builder.like(
                        root.<String>get(criteria.getKey()), "%" + criteria.getValue() + "%");
            } else {
                return builder.equal(root.get(criteria.getKey()), criteria.getValue());
            }
        }

    ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class UserSpecification implements Specification<GeoMap> {

    private SearchCriteria criteria;
    public UserSpecification(SearchCriteria criteria) {
        this.criteria = criteria;
    }

    @Override
    public Predicate toPredicate
            (Root<GeoMap> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder builder) {

        if (criteria.isEmpty()) return null;

        //.. search something

    }
}
```

Then

```
UserSpecification specName =
                    new UserSpecification(new SearchCriteria("name", ":", data.getName()));
UserSpecification specEnv =
                    new UserSpecification(new SearchCriteria("env", ":", data.getEnv()));

...

List list = gisMapRepository.findAll(Specification.where(specName).and(specEnv));
```